# PSTricks \psaxes-- aligning minor horizontal grid lines

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot, grids, pstricks-add

In the MWE below (a coordinate system having its first axis logarithmized),
major and minor ticks misalign.
I have tried to figure out which logic for I should apply for 
the `yticksize=0 8` option, but fiddling with this using trial and error
only gives me alignment of the **minor** gridlines - I fail to control 
the length of the **minor and major horizontal gridlines**.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pstricks-add}
\begin{document}
\psset{xunit=2,yunit=6}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.2,-0.05)(7.,2.)
  \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,
          xlogBase=10,comma,logLines=x,xsubticks=9,
          Ox={-4},% Origin for X
          dy=0.2,Dy=5,yticksize=0 8,ysubticks=4,
          Oy={-25},% Origin for Y
   ]
   (-1,0)(7.,2.0)%[,0][,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Coordinate system, first axis logarithmized - major and minor ticks misaligned!]

Thus my question:

How do I control the minor ticklines providing a rightmost (upper) limit somehow in concord with the units of the *x*-scale?

**Edit**

Shortened `\psset{}` statement.
Changing to `yticksize=0 8` solves alignment problem with
the **major horizontal ticklines**.

Added the picture below, corresponding to `yticksize=0 7`
in stead of `yticksize=0 8` (uppermost image).
Note that righthand endpoints of the minor gridlines and the major gridlines 
both move when changing the upper limit of `yticksize`, 
but they have **different lengths**, the major being the longer.
[image]

Comment: `ysubticksize=1`  It is a factor, relative to the major lines!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you have 8 units in x direction:

```
yticksize=0 8,ysubticksize=1,
```

and the sub ticks should be of the same size.

[image]

Comment: Yes, `yticksize=0 8,ysubticksize=1` fixes it. The value corresponding to `8` fixes the alignment issue across my implementations of this. Most obliged.

Comment: And `yticksize=8,ysubticksize=1` works, too.

Comment: Ahh, when ticks have default size, minor ticks are just that: about 90% -- smaller. The `ysubticksize=1` make size of the minor exactly 100% the size of the major ticks.

Comment: see documentation of pst-plot (Table 1) on page 26 for the default value.